# How to make a combined “List of Quadros”?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable, abntex2

I have a long list of risks I want to put in my document.

I manage to make it work with longtable as can be seen in pic1 (It's in portuguese because it's my masters disstertaion).

[image]

The problem I'm facing here is that there's a configuration in the template that separates Tables from "Quadros" (which are mainly used for text and have the outer lines). This table should be a "Quadro" not a "Tabela" and should be included in that list.

I'm facing this problem because I am using a document class called `abntex2` which takes everything into the right formatting for my masters and one of the things created was a new float Quadro to take care of this differentiation

This is how a Quadro is usually instantiated:

```
\begin{quadro}[htb]
\caption{Editores de Texto Livres}
\label{quadro:editores_texto_livres}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|r|}        \hline
Editor     & Multiplataforma & Específico para Latex \\ \hline
Kwriter    & Sim             & Não                   \\
Texmaker   & Sim             & Sim                   \\
Kile       & Sim             & Sim                   \\
Geany      & Sim             & Não                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{quadro}
```

If I try to encapsulate the long table in the Quadro float, it simply doesn't show up, And I'm pretty sure it's because it's just too long.

**So I was wondering:**

Is there a way to make tables be counted and named as quadros and have a **combined list of quadros**? I don't have any tables in my doc, just quadros. So if I could just have all of these floats be called the same and counted as the same it'd be perfect!

I'm using overleaf so I'm trying to get something that would work in a .cls class doc for the .tex but would be happy with anything that helps. BTW this is what the quadro config looks like:

```
\newcommand{\listquadroname}{Lista de quadros}
\newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\quadrorefname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\chartautorefname}{Quadro}

\addto\captionsenglish{% ingles
    \renewcommand{\listquadroname}{List of charts}
    \renewcommand{\quadroname}{Chart}
    \renewcommand{\quadrorefname}{Chart}
    \renewcommand{\chartautorefname}{Chart}
}

\newfloat{quadro}{htbp}{loq}[chapter]
\floatname{quadro}{\quadroname}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{quadro}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listquadroname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}
\renewcommand{\thequadro}{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@quadro}
\setfloatadjustment{quadro}{\centering}

\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> Is there a way to make tables be counted and named as quadros and have a combined list of quadros? I don't have any tables in my doc, just quadros. So if I could just have all of these floats be called the same and counted as the same it'd be perfect!

Since your document doesn't feature `table` floats that need to be kept separate from `quadro` floats, why not just map some of the strings that go with `table` and `longtable` environments into strings that go with `quadro` environments?

[image]

Addendum: I suppose another, much more elaborate, solution could consist of creating a `longquadro` environment that's based on the `longtable` environment. That way, your document could employ `cuadro` and `longcuadro` environments -- and also employ `table` and `longtable` (labelled as "Tabelas") environments should the need to do so arise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\addto\captionsbrazil{%
     \renewcommand{\tablename}{Quadro}
     \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de quadros}
     }
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment

\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage} % optional

%% enable advanced cross-referencing commands
\usepackage[brazilian,nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefname{table}{quadro}{quadros} % default is 'tabela' and 'tabelas'

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\bigskip\hrule

\begin{table}[h]     \caption{Olá}   \label{tab:1} \end{table}
\begin{longtable}{c} \caption{Mundo} \label{tab:2} \end{longtable}

\noindent
Algumas referências cruzadas para \Cref{tab:1,tab:2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey Mico, this is an interesting solution and it does work for it's intended purposes!

I can't stop using the float defined as quadro because of a bunch of other definitions that are running within the defined float that is a quadro.

How hard would it be to instantiate a longtable type of quadro? Like you mentioned in the appendum?

I'm asking because I plan to leave my configs to the masters program as a template for anyone who wants to use LATEX for their dissertation and not a terrible word template

Comment: @VictorArchela - May I suggest that you post a *new* query, in which you mention which document class you employ, describe how the `quadro` float type is defined, and ask how the `longtable` environment might have to be modified to create a `longquadro` environment? Thanks.

Comment: Ok will do that! Thanks for the help!