# How might the longtable environment have to be modified to create a longquadro environment?

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable

To give some context: I have a long list of risks I want to put in my document and managed to make it work using `longtable` as can be seen in pic1 (It's in portuguese because it's my masters disstertaion).

[image]

The problem I'm facing here is that longtables are always recognized as Tables and I would like to be able to use a custom float named `quadro`, that is created as part of the template I'm using which is defined below:

```
\newcommand{\listquadroname}{Lista de quadros}
\newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\quadrorefname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\chartautorefname}{Quadro}

\addto\captionsenglish{% ingles
    \renewcommand{\listquadroname}{List of charts}
    \renewcommand{\quadroname}{Chart}
    \renewcommand{\quadrorefname}{Chart}
    \renewcommand{\chartautorefname}{Chart}
}

\newfloat{quadro}{htbp}{loq}[chapter]
\floatname{quadro}{\quadroname}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{quadro}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listquadroname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}
\renewcommand{\thequadro}{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@quadro}
\setfloatadjustment{quadro}{\centering}

\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}

\begin{quadro}[htb]
\caption{Editores de Texto Livres}
\label{quadro:editores_texto_livres}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|r|}        \hline
Editor     & Multiplataforma & Específico para Latex \\ \hline
Kwriter    & Sim             & Não                   \\
Texmaker   & Sim             & Sim                   \\
Kile       & Sim             & Sim                   \\
Geany      & Sim             & Não                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{quadro}
```

That being said, how might I edit the `longtable` environment to create a `longquadro` environment that not only follows the same naming convention but also is included in the same lists (like List of Quadros).

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the question you just asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572550/how-to-make-a-combined-list-of-quadros  you can edit a question if it needs clarification, better than re-posting as a new question leaving both open.

Comment: also please post examples as complete documents that people can copy and run to see the issue,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - this posting isn't a full duplicate of the OP's earlier query (even though large parts of it are), which I answered. I suggested to the OP that he should post a new query to ask specifically about creating a `longquadro` environment that is to the `quadro` environment (defined with the help of the `newfloat` package) what the `longtable` environment is to the `table` environment.

Comment: @Mico OK (this is built in to v5 actually, but v5 isn't going to appear any time soon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a follow-up question of [Trying to use longtable to make it span multiple pages but can't control to which list it goes to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548013/79060), the following example is also based on the one given in the answer (posted by myself) there.

General notes:

- The key is to do the patch locally inside environment `longquadro`.
- To avoid the problem of nesting `\xpatchcmd\cmd{<... containing #1>}{}{<true>}{<false>}` inside a macro, `\LT@c@ption` is directly redefined rather than patched.

```tex
% for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572654
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[strut=off]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\listquadroname}{Lista de quadros}
\newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\quadrorefname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\chartautorefname}{Quadro}

\newfloat{quadro}{htbp}{loq}[chapter]
\floatname{quadro}{\quadroname}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{quadro}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thequadro}{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@quadro}

% define env "longquadro"
\newenvironment{longquadro}
  {\patch@longtable
   \longtable}
  {\endlongtable}

% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548021
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{
  \newcommand\patch@longtable{%
    \xpatchcmd\ltcaption@ORI@LT@array
      {\refstepcounter{table}}
      {\refstepcounter{quadro}}
      {}{\fail}%
    \renewcommand\LTcaptype{quadro}%
  }
}{
  \newcommand\patch@longtable{%
    \xpatchcmd\LT@array
      {\refstepcounter{table}}
      {\refstepcounter{quadro}}
      {}{}%
    % directly redefine "\LT@c@ption"
    \def\LT@c@ption##1[##2]##3{%
      \LT@makecaption##1\fnum@quadro{##3}%
      \def\@tempa{##2}%
      \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
         {\let\\\space
         \addcontentsline{loq}{quadro}{\protect\numberline{\thequadro}{##2}}}%
      \fi}%
  }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoftables
\listof{quadro}{\listquadroname}

\chapter{title}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{This is s table title}
\end{table}

\begin{quadro}[htb]
  \caption{This is a quadro title}
\end{quadro}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
  \caption{This is a longtable title} \\
  a & b \\
  c & d
\end{longtable}

\begin{longquadro}{cc}
  \caption{This is a longquadro title} \\
  a & b \\
  c & d
\end{longquadro}
\end{document}
```

[image: list of tables]
[image: Lista de quadros]
[image: chapter 1, four (long)table-like envs]

Comment: thanks @muzimuzhi once again being quick to propose an answer :)

Comment: I have tested the code but adding it to an empty overleaf project gives me an error when it comes to using the \AddToHook. Is it something I can change in the doc?

`The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.`

I don't want you to spent to much time thought because the above solution did work.

Comment: @VictorArchela Answer edited. The depending on latex2e 2020-10-01, a latex2e version that Overleaf hasn't provided yet, is removed.

Comment: Works now thanks @muzimuzi!

Comment: Hey @Muzimuzi, I have an update on the question here. The numbers work perfectly but I had a problem bringing it into my template because it changes the formatting of the list of quadros. Because \listofquadros is empty and you recommended the use of `\listof{quadro}{\listquadroname}`. The thing is a list entry in the template looks like this: "Quadro 1 - Name of the quadro . . . . . pagenumber". Is there a way to go back to using `\listofquadros` while having the caption package?

Comment: @VictorArchela If the output of list-of-quadros entry is OK, but you prefer `\listofquadros`, just `\newcommand\listofquadros{\listof{quadro}{\listquadroname}}`.

Comment: I am currently testing this snippet, but it breaks with 

`! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fail 
                 
l.174     \begin{longquadro}
                            {cc}
?`

I don't know where to look.

Comment: @GabrielAraújo Which version of latex (or texlive) do you use? Just double checked with my local updated texlive 2021 and overleaf.com's texlive 2020&21, the snippet  compiles with no errors. Maybe you dropped the `\makeatletter` and/or `\makeatother`?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, I use TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux, kpathsea version 6.3.3. I notice that this checking always fail `\xpatchcmd\ltcaption@ORI@LT@array
    {\refstepcounter{table}}
    {\refstepcounter{quadro}}
    {}{\fail}%`. So I removed the `\fail` command, and it works. But I know that it is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @GabrielAraújo Answer updated. If your example doesn't load `caption`, then that incompatibility should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%%changed to make generic
\providecommand{\listquadroname}{}
\providecommand{\quadroname}{}
\providecommand{\quadrorefname}{}
\providecommand{\chartautorefname}{}

\addto\captionsbrazil{%
  \renewcommand{\listquadroname}{Lista de quadros}%
  \renewcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}%
  \renewcommand{\quadrorefname}{Quadro}%
  \renewcommand{\chartautorefname}{Quadro}%
}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\listquadroname}{List of charts}%
  \renewcommand{\quadroname}{Chart}%
  \renewcommand{\quadrorefname}{Chart}%
  \renewcommand{\chartautorefname}{Chart}%
}
%%%

\newfloat{quadro}{htbp}{loq}% <--- changed
\counterwithin{quadro}{chapter}% <--- added
\floatname{quadro}{\quadroname}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{quadro}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listquadroname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}
\renewcommand{\thequadro}{\thechapter.\arabic{quadro}}% <--- changed
\setfloatadjustment{quadro}{\centering}

\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{longquadro}
 {%
  \let\c@table\c@quadro\let\thetable\thequadro
  \def\fnum@table{\quadroname{ }\thequadro}%
  \xpatchcmd{\NRorg@LT@c@ption}{{lot}{table}}{{loq}{quadro}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\NRorg@LT@c@ption}{{lot}{table}}{{loq}{quadro}}{}{}%
  \renewcommand{\theHtable}{quadro\thechapter.\arabic{quadro}}%
  \longtable
 }
 {\endlongtable}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofquadros

\chapter{First}

\begin{quadro}[htp]
\caption{Test}
\end{quadro}

\begin{longquadro}{|l|l|r|}
\caption{Editores de Texto Livres}
\label{quadro:editores_texto_livres}\\
\hline
Editor     & Multiplataforma & Específico para Latex \\ \hline
Kwriter    & Sim             & Não                   \\
Texmaker   & Sim             & Sim                   \\
Kile       & Sim             & Sim                   \\
Geany      & Sim             & Não                   \\ \hline
\end{longquadro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Check the changes I made to your code.

Comment: Update here, @egreg When Importing this config to my template the numbers worked perfectly but then I noticed that the quadrolist was skipping those quadros. After a LOT of testing and removing things in a test doc I found out I had this package: `\usepackage{caption}` which were overwriting the new macro and not adding the content to the loq. Is there a way to keep this package on without loosing your fix? If I remove it it breaks a bunch of other things.

Comment: do you know anything that might help? I might open a new question just for this but wanted to check either way

Comment: @VictorArchela Since `caption` modifies the meaning of `\caption`, one has to do a different patch. Following all the redefinitions is quite cumbersome. On the other hand, `abntex2` is based on `memoir` that has its own method for modifying captions and dealing with subfloats.